# How to send javascript value to views.py django

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to send a value from javascript to views.py function in Django.

The code as following:

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="get">

    <button id="button" name="button" onclick="click()">send</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="data" name="data" value="">
    <script>
        function click() {
            var d = 100
            document.getElementById("data").value = d;
            document.myform.submit();
        }
    </script>

</form>
```

In views.py,

```
def views(request): #assume function name is views
    result = request.GET.get("data")
```

, but this method is failed, please guide me.

Comment: why are you doing like this ? just use the traditional way. why do you need javascript anyway ?

Comment: you don't need js at all

Comment: This is an example. I execute a function by javascript and get a value "d", this value must send to django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="get">
    <button id="button" name="button" onclick="myFunction()">send</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="data" name="data" value="">
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var d = 100
            document.getElementById("data").value = d;
            console.log(document.getElementById("data").value);
        }
    </script>

</form>
```

Change the name of the function and comment the submit of the form.